# Testing Azure SQL DW Concurrency shows internally Azure is not running procedures concurrently

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I have read the Azure Concurrency and workload management in SQL Data Warehouse
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-develop-concurrency/
and understand the limits placed on the number of concurrent queries one can use based on scale, but what I cannot understand and thus raising the question here is when testing what the document states, I cannot get the results Azure claims are true. Running queries concurrently is still taking almost as long as running them serially.

For examples Here is a test example (just a test)
I have 5 stored procedures that when run individually they take around 1 second each to complete. So when I run all 5 serially they take around 5 seconds, this is expected but when I run all 5 sprocs concurrently I would expect them to complete in a little over 1 second but instead they take about 4.5-4.7 seconds to complete.

Can some Azure expert explain what could be going on?

I thought it could be resource contention but sys.dm_pdw_resource_waits shows no blockage while the 5 sprocs are running.

When I run sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests I see all 5 exec sproc queries being submitted withing a few ms. Same is true for Start_time and End_compile_time. the end_time for all 5 sprocs is again within a couple ms but the Total_elapsed_time is closer to 5000 ms instead of the expected 1000 ms. If I run any sproc by itself the duration is around 1000 ms. Its as if Concurrency will start all 5 sprocs at the same time but internally they are queued up and run sequentially. I was originally testing on a DW200 which has 8 slots which should be enough for my 5 sprocs. To be safe I scaled out to a DW1000 which allows me up to 32 concurrent queries (I am using smallrc) but that did not help this issue.

Here is how I tested this (using DW1000)

1. I loaded 1000 records into 5 separate stage tables
   (stage1,stage2,etc..)

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.Stage1
   (
        ShortId bigint NOT NULL
       ,TestName varchar(50) NOT NULL
       ,TestValue varchar(50) NOT NULL
       ,CreateDate DateTime NOT NULL 
   )
   WITH
   (
       DISTRIBUTION = HASH (ShortId)
   )
   ```
2. I created 5 fact tables (fact1,fact2, etc..) each table has the
   same 4 columns  as stage and is distributed using hash on the first
   column. I did not include a columnstore index (remember this is only
   a test)

   ```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.Fact1
   (
        ShortId bigint NOT NULL
       ,TestName varchar(50) NOT NULL
       ,TestValue varchar(50) NOT NULL
       ,CreateDate DateTime NOT NULL 
   )
   WITH
   (
       DISTRIBUTION = HASH (ShortId)
   )
   ```
3. I created 5 stored procedures that inserts data into fact from
   stage.

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TestLoad1
   AS
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO dbo.Fact1   --this is dbo.Fact2 in sproc 2 etc...
       SELECT 
          stg.ShortId
         ,stg.PropertyName
         ,stg.PropertyValue 
         ,stg.AcquistionTime
       FROM dbo.Stage1 stg
           WHERE stg.ShortId NOT IN (SELECT ShortId from dbo.Fact1) --Fact2 etc..
   END
   ```
4. In C# I created a quick test method that creates 5 connections,
   commands and uses BeginExecuteReader/EndExecuteReader to execute the
   sproc. (this is just a test, so forgive the style/code)

   ```
   SqlConnection cnn1 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Persist Security Info = True;User ID =<username>;Password = <password>;Pooling = False;MultipleActiveResultSets = False;Connect Timeout = 30;Encrypt = True;TrustServerCertificate = False");
   SqlConnection cnn2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Persist Security Info = True;User ID =<username>;Password = <password>;Pooling = False;MultipleActiveResultSets = False;Connect Timeout = 30;Encrypt = True;TrustServerCertificate = False");
   SqlConnection cnn3 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Persist Security Info = True;User ID =<username>;Password = <password>;Pooling = False;MultipleActiveResultSets = False;Connect Timeout = 30;Encrypt = True;TrustServerCertificate = False");
   SqlConnection cnn4 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Persist Security Info = True;User ID =<username>;Password = <password>;Pooling = False;MultipleActiveResultSets = False;Connect Timeout = 30;Encrypt = True;TrustServerCertificate = False");
   SqlConnection cnn5 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<database>;Persist Security Info = True;User ID =<username>;Password = <password>;Pooling = False;MultipleActiveResultSets = False;Connect Timeout = 30;Encrypt = True;TrustServerCertificate = False");

   SqlCommand cmd1;
   SqlCommand cmd2;
   SqlCommand cmd3;
   SqlCommand cmd4;
   SqlCommand cmd5;
   IAsyncResult result1;
   IAsyncResult result2;
   IAsyncResult result3;
   IAsyncResult result4;
   IAsyncResult result5;
   SqlDataReader reader1;
   SqlDataReader reader2;
   SqlDataReader reader3;
   SqlDataReader reader4;
   SqlDataReader reader5;

   cnn1.Open();
   cnn2.Open();
   cnn3.Open();
   cnn4.Open();
   cnn5.Open();

   cmd1 = new SqlCommand("dbo.TestLoad1", cnn1);
   cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.TestLoad2", cnn2);
   cmd3 = new SqlCommand("dbo.TestLoad3", cnn3);
   cmd4 = new SqlCommand("dbo.TestLoad4", cnn4);
   cmd5 = new SqlCommand("dbo.TestLoad5", cnn5);

   cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd4.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd5.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   result1 = cmd1.BeginExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
   result2 = cmd2.BeginExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
   result3 = cmd3.BeginExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
   result4 = cmd4.BeginExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);
   result5 = cmd5.BeginExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow);

   reader1 = cmd1.EndExecuteReader(result1);  //this is where the code waits for 5 seconds
   reader2 = cmd2.EndExecuteReader(result2);
   reader3 = cmd3.EndExecuteReader(result3);
   reader4 = cmd4.EndExecuteReader(result4);
   reader5 = cmd5.EndExecuteReader(result5);

   reader1.Close();
   reader2.Close();
   reader3.Close();
   reader4.Close();
   reader5.Close();
   ```

When debugging this C# code each statement is < 1ms until I get to the line reader1 = cmd1.EndExecuteReader(result1);
Here it will wait for 4-5 seconds then move on and every line after is again quick (<1ms).

During that delay if I run select * from sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests I see all 5 requests are queued up and running. If I continue to re-run the query duration keeps increasing then all of sudden (around 5 seconds) all 5 queries say they completed.

Any help would be appreciated in explaining what I am doing wrong or what Azure SQL DW is doing internally.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

SQL Data Warehouse allows for a single query to utilize all CPU or IO with a single query.  When query is able to fully utilize a resource, adding another query which also contends for the same resource will mean that both will run slower.  That is, if you have a query which uses 100% of CPU and run another query which also uses 100% concurrently, both queries will take twice as long.  The benefit of this is that a single query will run as fast as possible and two queries which contend for different resources will also run as fast as possible.  When you run a test like the one above, where all queries are essentially identical, it would be expected that running the tests serially or concurrently will take the same amount of time.

To further investigate your results, you might find the [monitoring article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-manage-monitor/) beneficial.  In addition to looking at sys.dm_pdw_exec_requests, try taking a look at sys.dm_pdw_request_steps (execution time by Distributed SQL step), which I would expect to account for the majority of the 5 seconds as well as sys.dm_pdw_sql_requests (execution time by distribution).

BTW, above you mentioned that you didn't add a columnstore index for your test.  In SQL DW the [default table type is clustered columnstore](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-tables-index/#clustered-columnstore-indexes).  To remove this index, change your WITH clause as follows...

> WITH
>   (
>       DISTRIBUTION = HASH (ShortId), HEAP
>   )

Hope this helps.