# Identifying needed statistics - Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: azure-synapse

Is there any hint or directive that can be used with EXPLAIN of a query on Azure SQL Data Warehouse that would return recommended statistics that were not available for the optimizer?  Alternatively is there a tool that can analyze a workload and make any recommendation.

Comment: I submitted this as an enhancement request https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/17597272-add-recommended-statistics-to-explain-output .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today, no. Right now the recommendation is to create statistics on every column as these are needed to create an optimal parallel query plan (I.e. how to move data around between nodes to return a result since it's a MPP architecture).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-best-practices#maintain-statistics

An example of how to script this out can be found here as well (example H).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-statistics#examples-create-statistics

Comment: Really helpful answer - I was trying to understand the need for statistics when tables are columnstore by default. Important for my to get into a distributed way of thinking.

Comment: @Anthony, if the recommendation is to create statistics on every column then why Azure SQL DW does not create itself? What's the reason it is not done by nature?

Comment: It would appear engineering is working on this, please feel free to add your +1 https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/18024499-automatic-generation-and-updating-of-table-statist

Answer (score 1):

As you know, statistics should be created (according to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-statistics)):

> on columns involved in JOINs, GROUP BY, HAVING and WHERE clauses.

There are no tools to do this (yet), but if you have access to the EXPLAIN plans they give you certain information.  For example the `shuffle_columns` element lists all columns involved in a `SHUFFLE_MOVE`:

```
<shuffle_columns>col;</shuffle_columns>
```

as well as myriad other information.  Review the annotation I did of an Azure SQL Data Warehouse plan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39799965/simple-performance-test-on-azure-sql-data-warehouse/39806943#39806943).

Lastly, (and I haven't actually done this, I've only been thinking about doing it), you could set up a copy of your database on SQL Server 2016, bearing in mind the syntax differences (eg distribution, lack of unique indexes etc).  this would give you access to certain useful resources like execution plans, including index suggestions, and certain trace flags which tell you what stats were used.  I mean the database engines and indexing are really different so I don't know how worthwhile this might be.  I'll post back if I progress my thinking on this.  I do find the question "Why is this query going slow?" much harder to answer on this platform that ordinary "box product" SQL Server because the tools aren't as mature yet.

Comment: I'd be really interested in seeing the results, however, like you I am skeptical because statistics in SQL DW and PDW are not only used for their traditional purposes, but also used to estimate the cost of data movement for the parallel query plan.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning the recommendation is to put statistics on all columns as a starting point and only pair back as needed, to ensure the most optimal parallel query plan. Even if a column isn't in a JOIN, GROUP BY, HAVING, or WHERE clause, excluding them you run the risk of executing unnecessary or non-optimal data movement between nodes in the platform.