# Why is there no execution plan in Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure, ssms, azure-synapse

I am working on storing data in Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

I am trying to look at my indexes usage and see execution plans but none of them are shown in SSMS.

**Question**

Why is there no execution plan in Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

**Update**

I am using SSMS version 13.0.16106.4 (SQL Server 2016).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three methods of viewing execution plans for Azure SQL Data Warehouse:

1. Use the [EXPLAIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/explain-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7) command before any SQL command to view the text execution plan for that command, eg

   ```
   EXPLAIN
   SELECT * FROM yourTable;
   ```

For an example of interpreting these plans see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39806943/1527504).

2. Version of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) from 17.5 onwards have support for visual execution plans

[image: SSMS 17.5]

Download version 17.x or [later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).  More details [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/unlock-query-performance-with-sql-data-warehouse-using-graphical-execution-plans/).

3. Through the Azure portal, which is really a wrapper for [DBCC PDW_SHOWEXECUTIONPLAN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-pdw-showexecutionplan-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016-au7).

Armed with these three methods, you are now no doubt well equipped to view execution plans for Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Comment: I did not realize I was using an old version of SSMS :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Actual execution plans within SSMS do not work in Azure DW, (which changed to Azure Synapse, which changed to SQL Dedicated Pools.) Please prove me wrong.